# Nested tables in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-table

I'm building a web site and I used nested tables, and the code works  fine in Chrome, and Firefox and doesn't really show up in the way I want in Internet Explorer.

Below is the code for the table:

```
<table width=940>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="../../images/fix_header.jpg" alt="ローンシミュレーション"  width="500"   height="30"/>

                <table width="500px" cellPadding="10px">
                    <tr>
                        <td>金額</td> 
                        <td><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" size="20"　>円</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>期間</td>
                        <td>

                            <input type="radio"  name="bonus" value="1x"/>
                            1年
                            <input type="radio"  name="bonus" value="3x"
                             />
                            ３年
                            <input type="radio"  name="bonus" value="5x"
                            />
                            5年
                        </td>

                    </tr>   

                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td align="right">
                        <input type="reset" value="リセット" style="width: 150px; height: 40px;">
                        <input type="submit" value="計算" onclick="calculate()" style="width: 150px; height: 40px;">
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table >

            <br>
            <table width="500px" >

            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <th >
                    1年<br>＜単利型＞
                </th>
                <th>
                    3年<br>＜半年複利型＞
                </th>
                <th>
                    5年<br>＜半年複利型＞
                </th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th >
                    受取利息<br>
                    （税引後）
                </th>
                <td>
                    <p id="intrest1" style="color:#E64040;margin-bottom:20px; font-weight:bold; font-size:20px; " >0円</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p id="intrest2" style="color:#E64040;margin-bottom:20px; font-weight:bold; font-size:20px; " >0円</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p id="intrest3" style="color:#E64040;margin-bottom:20px; font-weight:bold; font-size:20px; " >0円</p>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th >
                    全額<br>
                    （利息込）

                </th>
                <td>
                    <p id="tot1" style="color:#E64040;margin-bottom:20px; font-weight:bold; font-size:20px; " >0円</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p id="tot2" style="color:#E64040;margin-bottom:20px; font-weight:bold; font-size:20px; " >0円</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p id="tot3" style="color:#E64040;margin-bottom:20px; font-weight:bold; font-size:20px; " >0円</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </form>


            </table>
```

I hope this information is sufficient; I'll try to explain from words how it appears:

In Internet Explorer the single row `<tr>` displays in two lines one below another where I want to display in one row in one line.

I hope you get what I'm saying... I really appreciate if any one can help me.

Answer (score 0):

The [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) feed with your code throws several errors, beyond them

> End of file seen and there were open elements.
>
> Unclosed element table. (table width=940)

You should try again after first correcting the errors.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you could try these steps to make your code valid:

- Close the outer table, you are missing `</td></tr></table>` at the end.
- Remove the `</form>` tag from where it is, it is not opened anywhere. You should probably enclose the whole outer table in `<form></form>` pair.
- Replace `＜単利型＞` and the other table header fields with `&lt;単利型&gt;`, you should use [HTML entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) for `<>` characters

After that, the result looks the same for me in IE and in Firefox. Is it only an issue with IE (and what version)? I cannot see  in more detail what you want from the result from your question.